# Does setup.py script will trigger subpackage's setup.py script?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I am studying how does the project **scikit-learn** setup. The following shows the basic skeleton of the project scikit-learn.
I wonder that when someone typed `python setup.py build_ext -i` in the top-level directory, does it trigger the `setup.py` script to run?

```
scikit-learn
     |-----------Makefile
     |-----------**setup.py**
     |-----------sklearn (package)
                    |-------------__init__.py
                    |-------------setup.py
                    |-------------cluster(package)
                                     |----------------__init__.py
                                     |----------------setup.py
                                     |........
                    |-------------utils(package)
                                     |----------------__init__.py
                                     |----------------setup.py
                                     |.........
```

Comment: You need to put all the required packages (including your own) in the setup.py `packages` variable (https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html)

Comment: @Mogi scikit-learn used numpy.distutils.misc_util.Configuration.add_subpackage to add package, but the top-level directory's setup.py only add_subpackage('sklearn')